# ¿cómo mostrar un toast centrado en la pantalla en Android?

Tags: android

**Este es mi código  PHP.**

```
 <?php
    try{ 
    $usuario = "root"; 
   $password = "123456"; 
   $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', $usuario,   $password);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
 }catch(PDOException $e){ 
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage(); 
} 
   define('MYSQL_ERROR_DUPLICATE_KEY', '1062');
  $sql=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario(Code,user,Pass,TipoUsuario)   VALUES (:Code, :user, :Pass, :TipoUsuario)");
  $sql->bindParam(':Code',$_POST['Code']);  
  $sql->bindParam(':user',$_POST['user']);
  $sql->bindParam(':Pass',$_POST['Pass']);      
 $sql->bindParam(':TipoUsuario',$_POST['TipoUsuario']); 
 if($sql->execute())
{
// Código de éxito
    print json_encode(
        array(
            'estado' => '1',
            'mensaje' => 'Creación éxitosa')
    );
}
else
{
if ($e->errorInfo[1] == MYSQL_ERROR_DUPLICATE_KEY) {
       // Código de error
    print json_encode(
        array(
            'estado' => '2',
            'mensaje' => 'Ya  existe un registro  con este  código')
      );
   }
}  

 ?>
```

**Este es mi código android(Java).**

```
private void addUsuario(){

    final String Code=et1.getText().toString().trim();
    final String user=et2.getText().toString().trim();
    final String Pass=et3.getText().toString().trim();
    final String TipoUsuario=muestraUser.getSelectedItem().toString();


    class AddUsuario extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(addUsuario.this, "Adding...", "Wait...", false, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(addUsuario.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(Config.KEY_USER_CODE, Code);
            params.put(Config.KEY_USER_USUARIO,user);
            params.put(Config.KEY_USER_PASS, Pass);
            params.put(Config.KEY_USER_TIPOUSER,TipoUsuario);

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_ADD_USER, params);
            return res;
        }
    }
    AddUsuario ae = new AddUsuario();
    ae.execute();
}
```

**Este es  el  código que deseo implementar  para  mostrar  mensaje.**

```
 private void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {

    try {
        // Obtener estado
        String estado = response.getString("estado");
        // Obtener mensaje
        String mensaje = response.getString("mensaje");

        switch (estado) {
            case "1":
                // Mostrar mensaje
               Toast respuesta1= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                respuesta1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.LEFT,0,0);
                respuesta1.show();
                break;

            case "2":
                // Mostrar mensaje
               Toast respuesta2= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                respuesta2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.LEFT,0,0);
                respuesta2.show();
                break;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Este es mi config donde  almaceno las  URL.**

```
public class Config {
        //Direccion de  mi script para el CRUD usuario
       public static final String      URL_ADD_USER="http://10.0.2.2/ProyectoAndroid/addUser.php";

  //Keys that will be used to send the request to php scripts User
   public static final String KEY_USER_CODE = "Code";
   public static final String KEY_USER_USUARIO = "user";
   public static final String KEY_USER_PASS = "Pass";
   public static final String KEY_USER_TIPOUSER = "TipoUsuario";

 //JSON Tags
public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="result";
```

}

Comment: Quieres mostrar el toast centrado ?

Comment: SÍ  @Ashley Josianne, lo que  pasa  que no se  como implementar procesarRespuesta()  dentro dentro del código Java(addUsuario())

Comment: Pero tu Asyntask cumple su función ? por que entiendo que solo tienes problemas para mostrar un mensaje segun el titulo ...

Comment: @Ashley Josianne,la  duada  que tengo es en que  parte de la función addUsuario() puedo ejecutar  la  función  procesarRespuesta.

Comment: en el doInBackground van los mensajes de si finalizo el proceso correctamente o no ..

Comment: @Sofia mediante un Toast no se puede centrar el mensaje, para esto necesitas un Custom Toast.

Answer (score 4):

Mostrar un `Toast` centrado en la pantalla puedes realizarlo definiendo la posición mediante el método [setGravity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#setGravity(int,%20int,%20int)).

Ejemplo:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(test.this,"Jorgesys was here @Center", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

---

#### Toast personalizado (Custom Toast).

Otra buena opción es realizar un "Toast personalizado".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego un método para realizar esto:

```
  public static void showCustomToast(String msg, int duration, int position, Context ctx){
        try{
            if(!"".equals(msg)){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
                TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textToShow);
                text.setText(msg);
                Toast toast = new Toast(ctx.getApplicationContext());
                switch(position){
                    case TOAST_TOP:
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
                        break;
                    case TOAST_CENTER:
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                        break;
                    case TOAST_BOTTOM:
                    default:
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                        break;
                }
                toast.setDuration(duration);
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();
            }
        }catch(IllegalStateException ise){
            Log.e(TAG, "ise showCustomToast(), " + ise.getMessage());
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "e showCustomToast(), " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

y el layout del custom toast:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/custom_toast"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="8dp"
              android:background="@drawable/bakground_custom_toast">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageViewToast"
               android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
               android:contentDescription="@null"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textToShow"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="hai!"
              android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewToast"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```